# How to convert list of Object into Specified format String using JS

Tags: javascript

what is the best way to convert below array into a string and `Name, value` should be separated by `:` Json objects are separated by `|`.

```
let arr = [
    {
     "name":"abc",
     "value":"21"
    },
    {
     "name":"abcd",
     "value":"212"
    }
];

function arrToString(arr){
 //logic
 return "abc:21|abcd:212"
}

console.log(arrToString(ar));
```

Expected output: "abc:21|abcd:212"

I have used this logic but I don't like this. I need more efficient logic.

```
let arr = [{
        "name": "abc",
        "value": "21"
    },
    {
        "name": "abcd",
        "value": "212"
    }
];


function setKey(arr) {
    let temp = "";
    arr.forEach((ele, index) => {
        let name = ele.name;
        let value = ele.value;
        if (arr.length - 1 == index) {
            temp = temp + name + ":" + value
        } else {
            temp = temp + name + ":" + value + "|";
        }
    });
    console.log(temp);
}
setKey(arr);
```

Comment: Sure, we can help you. Please add what have you tried, no matter how small

Comment: sure ,i have edited my question

Comment: Ok. Your code is very efficient IMHO. Bit lengthier than other answers. You can directly use `ele.value` etc, instead of a different variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of the `map` and `join` function like this:

```
function arrToString(arr) {
    return arr.map(item => `${item.name}:${item.value}`).join("|")
}
```

In this case the `map` function, which is a higher-order function, applies a function for each item in the `arr` array. In this case, we create the desired string for each item. The `join` function combines all the strings (e.g. `abc:21`, `abcd:212`) together by separating the values with a pipe (`|`)

Answer (score 1):

```
function arrToString(arr){
 let returnString = ''
 arr.forEach((item, index) => {
   if(index !== 0) returnString += '|'
   returnString += `${item.name}:${item.value}`
 })
 return returnString
}
```

Hope this will solve your question

Answer (score 1):

You can easily perform the conversion by exploiting the functional features of Javascript, in particular the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
function arrToString(arr){
    return arr.map(x => x.name + ":" + x.value).join('|')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@danieleds'a answer with an arrow function :)

`const arrToString = arr => arr.map(x => x.name + ":" + x.value).join('|')`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way with slice(which is used to remove characters from strings or elements from array):

```
function arrToString(arr){
 let ans = "";
  for(let i = 0 ; i < arr.length;i++){
   ans += (arr[i].name + ":" + arr[i].value);
    ans+= "|";
 }
 ans = ans.slice(0,-1);
 return ans
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In another simple way,

```
function objToStr(objArr){
    let strArray = [];
    objArr.forEach((item) => {
        strArray.push(item.name+":"+item.value);
    })
    return strArray.join("|");
}
```